# Understanding question about Sines and Cosines

Tags: trigonometry

I need some help answering a question on sines and cosines. I am very familiar with these but the problem is that i learned these in my mothgerlanguage and not in english. So although im familiar with the concept, i don’t really understand the question because of language bariers. I hope someone can explain the question to me and tell me what theyre asking me to do.

I’ll explain for each part what I didn’t understand. the question i got:

Solve for α in the oblique triangle ABC; AB = 30; AC = 15 and angle B = 20°
Oblique triangle ABC; AB = 30; AC = 15 and angle B = 20°

1. Type out the two equations substituting the numbers from the diagram. (What do they mean with substituting numbers from the diagram? Do they want me to calculate the missing numbers on the triangle, as in BC and the angles from A and C?)
2. Type out the Law of Sines set of relationships and type out the most appropriate version to use the Law of Cosines for this solution. (Do they want me to calculate α (BC) using either of the two laws?)
3. Solve for a using both methods (show step by step work) ( I don’t understand what they mean here)

I hope my question was a bit clear!

Comment: You are supposed to use the given side lengths and angle measures to solve for $\alpha$ and $a$.  The way I interpret the instructions is that you are first supposed to solve for $\alpha$ (although it helps to find $\gamma$ first), then solve for $a$ twice, once using the Law of Sines and once using the Law of Cosines.

Comment: This is what I ended up with on question one:
a/sin(A) = 15/sin(20) = 30/sin(C).
a² = 15² + 30² - 2·15·30·cos(A)

But when I try to calculate a using the sines equation I end up with an answer indecating that angle A is 116,8 degrees which makes the triangle not oblique??? So that goes against what the question states? I don’t understand what I did wrong

Comment: An oblique triangle is a triangle that is not a right triangle.  You obtained an obtuse triangle, which is fine.  When I just tried this problem, I found that there were two solutions.  Using the Law of Sines, I obtain $\sin C = 2\sin(20^\circ)$.  One solution is $C = \arcsin(2\sin(20^\circ)) \approx 43.16^\circ \implies \alpha = 116.84^\circ$.  The other solution is $C = 180^\circ - \arcsin(2\sin(20^\circ)) \approx 137.84^\circ \implies \alpha = 23.16^\circ$.  In each case, you can then solve for $a = BC$.